# No hash found for gcc-7.4.0.tar.xz in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: gcc, make

I am new in Linux and ubuntu. I'm trying to perform make in ubuntu terminal. But get an error: `No hash found for gcc-7.4.0.tar.xz` as in screenshot. GCC is installed, and the version is 7.5.0.

[image]

I'm trying to install gcc-7 to fix my problem, via `sudo apt install gcc-7 g++-7`, but get error that it is necessary to install some dependencies, more than 20 and I don't know how to do it. How I can fix this error? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What are the contents of *builddir*? What exactly are you trying to compile?